# Showing different nav link, depending on which page you navigate from

Tags: html

Apologies if the title is misleading hopefully I can explain myself here..

Basically, to simplify it.. I have a product page, we'll call it "Apple"
"Apple" is available one of two ways, either by coming from the page "fruit" or from the page "Popular Brand"

Now, at the top of the "Apple" page I have a set of navigation links.. similar to this..

**Home -  Categories -  Fruit - Contact**

Now, this is all well and good if you arrived at "Apple" from the "Fruit" page, however, as it stands, if you arrive from the "Popular Brand" page, you are still shown the same navigation links.

where as I would like it to show..

**Home  -  Categories  -  Popular Brand  -  Contact**

So my question is,

How do I make the link change depending on which page you originally came from, without making duplicate pages for either situation.

The code is nothing special, just basic links..

```
<ul>

<li> <a href="index.html">Home</a></li>

<li> <a href="categories.html">Categories</a></li>

<li> <a href="fruit.html">Fruit</a></li>

<li class="current_page_item"><a href="fruit.html">Fruit</a></li>

<li> <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
```

Hope I have explained myself clearly, and appreciate any help with this.

Lee

Comment: This would usually involve some sort of scripting language, either on the client-side or on the server-side

Comment: Can people also navigate directly to "Apple" by typing its url into their address bar?

Comment: @JonathanSampson I guess that is possible, and if that was the case, it wouldn't matter which link was shown..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append to the source to the url itself, so that it ends with `?source=fruit` or possibly even `?source=popular%20brand`. Search out this `source` variable, and hide one of two links in response.

Suppose this were your HTML:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <a href="#">Home</a> 
    <a href="#">Categories</a> 
    <a href="#" data-toggle>Fruit</a> 
    <a href="#" data-toggle>Popular Brand</a> 
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

Originally it has both of our links within it: Fruit, and Popular Brands. Next comes a function to help us lookup values in `document.location.search`:

```
function getParam ( p ) {
    var search = decodeURIComponent( document.location.search );
    var val, exp = new RegExp( "[?&]" + p + "=([^&]+)" );
    return ( val = search.match( exp ) ) ? val[1] : false;
}
```

This works by passing in a name, and returns either the corresponding value, or `false`. Next we will get, or provide, a value for `source`. If our `getParam` function can't find one, we'll simply assume it is "Fruit":

```
var source = getParam( "source" ) || "Fruit";
```

Now we gather a reference to all of the links in our nav area:

```
var links = document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("a"), 
    count = links.length, a;
```

At this point we cycle over the collection of `a` elements. If they have the `data-toggle` attribute, we check to see whether their text matches the source text. If it does not, we hide it. This means `?source=fruit` will hide the Popular Brand link, and `?source=popular%20brand` will hide the Fruit link.

```
while ( a = links[ --count ] ) {
    if ( a.hasAttribute("data-toggle") )
        if ( (a.textContent || a.innerText).toLowerCase() !== source.toLowerCase() )
            a.parentElement.removeChild( a );
}
```

You can see this online by viewing the following URLs:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/dLkfc/show/
- http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/dLkfc/show/?source=fruit
- http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/dLkfc/show/?source=popular%20brand

Comment: Thank you! I'll be sure to check that out when im back in work tomorrow!

Comment: Hi @Jonathan , I've had chance to have a look.. all 3 of your links show the same fiddle, with all links visable, is this correct? Ideally where you have `?source=fruit` I would like to hide **popular brand** from the links menu, and vice-versa, `?source=popular%20brand` would hide **fruit** from the menu.. does that make sense? Once again, I appreciate all your help.

Comment: @LeeHibberd As it is right now, `?source=fruit` hides "fruit" - I'm sorry for getting this backwards. I'm more concerned with the fact that all links are showing up for you; what browser (and version) are you using?

Comment: @LeeHibberd I suspect you're seeing all links because you're in an older version of IE (perhaps 8), which doesn't support `querySelectorAll`. I'll update the script.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using Firefox though, whether that makes a difference?

Comment: @LeeHibberd You should have no problem in Firefox. Please try the links again and see if they work for you now.

Comment: I have just tried your link in IE and it works fine, so it appears firefox is casuing the problem..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27944/discussion-between-jonathan-sampson-and-lee-hibberd)

Answer (score 0):

You use a scripting language to display different things depending on parameters passed along in the url, like `?from=fruit` or `?from=popular_brand` as per your example above.

Comment: Thank you for the comment.. as I am still very new to this, where abouts would I insert this?

Comment: You'd put it at the end of the URL and then collect the data on page load. If you're just starting out, I'd recommend JavaScript or PHP.

Comment: I appreciate your help on this, and im sure your answer is the one i need, but your comments are going straight over my head. I have very limited knowledge when it comes to web design, and im afraid i need more of a detailed answer. exactly where do i need to put the code, and what javascript would i need to use to collect the data.. Thanks again.

Comment: Here's a [reasonable example](http://papermashup.com/read-url-get-variables-withjavascript/) of what I'm suggesting, using JavaScript - which is client-side. Look at the first example only - that should be what you need.